# From where can i download RS126 protein dataset in *.mat format?

Tags: python, biopython, protein-database

I've been working on a Protein Secondary Structures Prediction Project. I am unable to find the RS 126 dataset online. I found a list of proteins in that database. I am looking for the same proteins after running a PSI BLAST search on them and in *.mat (MATLAB dataset) format.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can point you to the legacy [Jpred2 website](http://www.compbio.dundee.ac.uk/jpred4/legacy/data/). It is not exactly what you want, but the first dataset (513_distribute.tar.gz) contains 117 of the 126 proteins in the RS126 dataset and you should read the paper for details. It is also not in .mat format, but parsing it is trivial - let me know if you need help with that.

Comment: what about the remaining 9 proteins?

Comment: As I said, you should read the paper for details why they removed the 9 sequences.